# GTK3 Passing Struct to Callback Function - Exception has occurred, segmentation error

Tags: c++, exception, struct, callback, gtk

I have created a structure, outside of any functions:

```c
//create structure
typedef struct _LabelPointers
{
    GtkWidget *readstringslabel;
    GtkWidget *snoteslabel;
    GtkWidget *fnoteslabel;
    GtkWidget *genericnoteslabel;
    GtkWidget *tabslabel;
    GtkWidget *chordslabel;
} MyLabelPointers;
```

Then, I have created a structure, inside calling function, of labels:

```c
//create structure of widget label pointers (to be passed to functions)
MyLabelPointers labelpointers;
    
labelpointers.readstringslabel = gtk_label_new("0");
labelpointers.snoteslabel = gtk_label_new("0");
labelpointers.fnoteslabel = gtk_label_new("0");
labelpointers.genericnoteslabel = gtk_label_new("0");
labelpointers.tabslabel = gtk_label_new("0");
labelpointers.chordslabel = gtk_label_new("0");
```

Then, I have connected the callback as follows, passing `&labelpointers`:

```c
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "key_press_event",G_CALLBACK(pressspacebar), &labelpointers);
```

The called function is as follows, accepting `*labelpointers`:

```c
gboolean pressspacebar (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event,  MyLabelPointers *lpointers)
```

I then try to update the text in `labelpointers->readstringslabel` as in:

```c
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(lpointers->readstringslabel), cdata);
```

or as in:

```c
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(lpointers->readstringslabel), "NEW DATA");
```

And it all compiles, and runs, until I get "Exception has occurred, segmentation error". Just before the error, I print to shell as follows:

```cpp
cout<<"before\n";
cout<<"lpointers.readstringslabel = "<<lpointers->readstringslabel<<"\n";
cout<<"lpointers.readstringslabel = "<<&lpointers->readstringslabel<<"\n";
cout<<"type = " << typeid(lpointers->readstringslabel).name() << "\n";
```

and get:

```
before
lpointers.readstringslabel = 0x4
lpointers.readstringslabel = 0x7fffffffd570
type = P10_GtkWidget
```

I hope that this is enough information for someone to help me with this problem on which I've been working now for three days. Unfortunately, even Google hasn't been much help in leading me out of this.

Comment: Please try providing a complete and minimal example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: I have determined that this is a threading issue.  I created the window in one function, called a second function based on a <spacebar> press which was to do a routine to update the labels in the original window - which I have learned is a no-no.  I am now creating a second window in the called function and for which the routine will show the updated labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the structure as a stack variable (`MyLabelPointers labelpointers`), this is discarded at the end of the function, and not available anymore when the callback gets called. You have to dynamically allocate your structure with (`g_new()` -like functions) - and then `g_free()` it when no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. I ended-up creating global widgets and avoided passing these pointers/variables. Which works for me.  Thanks again.